# Unsuccessful download with Download Manager Android 9

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to download a file from the internet with DownloadManager on Android 9, but I only get unsuccessful download. This is what I am testing:

My Manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

My code to download it:

```
    private final String FILE_NAME = "SampleDownloadApp.apk";
    String apkUrl = "https://androidwave.com/source/apk/app-pagination-recyclerview.apk";

public void download(Context context) {
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri mUri = Uri.parse(apkUrl);
    DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(mUri);
    r.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/" + FILE_NAME_2);
    r.setDestinationUri(uri);
    dm.enqueue(r);
}
```

I have tried android: usesCleartextTraffic = "true" in the manifest but then nothing happens. I never get any errors neither in logcat nor in run.

I followed this tutorial: https://androidwave.com/download-and-install-apk-programmatically/

I have no idea what the problem may be, any solution?

Help with this!

Comment: did you enable permission from app setting for storage?

Comment: Yes, is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is something wrong with you URL tried following and its working

```
private final String FILE_NAME = "SampleDownloadApp.apk";
    String apkUrl = "https://d-10.winudf.com/b/APK/Y29tLm5lbW8udmlkbWF0ZV80MzUxMV9iOTJjMTFkZA?_fn=VmlkTWF0ZSBIRCBWaWRlbyBEb3dubG9hZGVyIExpdmUgVFZfdjQuMzUxMV9hcGtwdXJlLmNvbS5hcGs&_p=Y29tLm5lbW8udmlkbWF0ZQ&am=cCsiKSeBEin6IVuzn-Q2PA&at=1590661203&k=3c1a8eca32edf42751cb3f5fa102d0205ed0e1d3";

public void download(Context context) {
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri mUri = Uri.parse(apkUrl);
    DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(mUri);
    r.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    r.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, FILE_NAME);
    dm.enqueue(r);
}
```

Comment: This works, but, what is the reason? What happen with the other URL? If i enter in the URL with Chrome it download the apk.

Comment: it seem url is not secure check url in chrome in info they are saying it is not secure